# How to find mean of n previous rows in a column in pandas based on date criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
value1 value2 value3 date

17    21    22     2005-04-01 12:05:00

19    20    24     2005-04-01 12:06:00

16    26    23     2005-04-01 12:07:00
```

I need to transform it somehow, so the values of each row with date ending with .05:00 (5th minute of each hour) will be equal to average value of previous 60 rows.

I tried to use groupby based on datetime, it does provide average values for each hour (00 - 59), but i need to adjust it for my case.

In the end I would like to have something like this:

```
  value1 value2 value3 date

  17    21    22     2005-04-01 12:05:00

  19    20    24     2005-04-01 13:05:00

  16    26    23     2005-04-01 14:05:00
```

where 17 for instance is average of 60 previous values in value1 column.

Comment: Could you explain more that you mean with _"average value of previous 60 rows_"? I dont see anything change to the values in your expected output. Only the `date` column changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a rolling mean on 60 minutes windows (makes sure, that `date` column is `datetime64[ns]` dtype, if not, convert it beforehand), then you can select the necessary rows with `.loc[]`:

```
df.rolling('H', on='date').mean().loc[lambda x: x['date'].dt.minute == 5]
```

See the docs for further details on [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).